# Raster layer transparency based on another raster layer values (QGIS)

Tags: qgis, raster, transparency-opacity

I'm working in QGIS.

I have two raster layers:

1. an unique values raster, representing the number of wind turbines visible for each pixel (reds palette)
2. a raster with values (0-20000) expressing the distances in meters from the wind turbines

I'd like to obtain a transparency for the 1) raster based on 2) raster values that fades from 0 (100% opacity) to 20000 (0% opacity).

I tried setting the 1) "Layer Rendering" to "Darken" superimposed on 2) raster, as you can see in the screenshot below. But the result is not so nice.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After various experiments and attempts, I have developed the procedure that best meets my needs, that is, blurring (with transparency) the visibility map of the wind turbines (MIT_150m) as a function of the distance from them (proximity_20km):

1. Reclassified the `proximity_20km` raster with `Reclassify by table` tool obtaining 10 classes of 2000 meters each in values from 1 to 10.
2. Set a transparency table for the reclassified raster starting from 1 (closest) = 0% up to 10 (farthest) 100% from the turbines.
3. Set the `Symbology` for the reclassified proximity raster to `Singleband pseudocolor` and `Discrete` with a single class (1-10) black color with 70% opacity.
4. In `Layer Rendering` for the MIT_150m raster set the `Blending mode` in `Overlay`.
5. Make visible the two raster with MIT_150m directly over the reclassified proximity layer.

Below is the result, pretty good for my purpose.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. [Merge](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/gdal/rastermiscellaneous.html#gdalmerge) the two rasters and check the box <kbd>Place each input file into a separate band</kbd>
2. On the resulting layer, use [`Custom transparency options`](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_properties.html#transparency-properties) and select the `Transparency band`.

---

Alternatively, you could also use blending mode `Screen`, see screenshot. You can duplicate the layer to cumulatively add the blending modes (play around with different settings).

[image]

Comment: I've set the 'proximity' layer as transparency, but the results are non what I expected, as you can see here [map screenshot](https://i.imgur.com/Ac2IBeW.png)

Comment: Not exactly sure what you want to achieve. Can you share your raster layers?

Comment: I'd like to obtain a fading transparence for the red colored map (MIT_150m) based on values of the proximity map values, from 0 m (100% transparence) to 20000 m (0% transparence). You can find the two raster layers [here](https://mega.nz/folder/XJ9m0T4A#jAMkruGz6NOPSyDihu5Cbg)

Comment: See updated answer